# Git precommit issues

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, npm, po

Well I'm in a project working with react, we have our own git hook, installed like this

```
mkdir -p .git/hooks && git config --local commit.template hooks/commit-msg
```

Also we're using `*.po` files with `i18n` library. My issue, every time I do a commit backslashes in po file are changed to slashes. I'm coding with MacOS.

I know is kind of stupid question but is happening and I have no idea how to solve it.

[UPDATE]: Here's hook

```
# Add title above: one-line description of change tagged with JIRA
# Example:
# [POS-123456] Catch Exception thrown by CTM Client
# [NOJIRA] Remove unused Math utility class

Description & Context
=====================

# Explain what the change is (at least 1 sentence, but can be a couple paragraphs for a significant change)
# Explain why this change is necessary


Related Links
-------------

# Add links to JIRA issues, GitHub issues, and/or Confluence page, or any other links providing context.
# Example: GitHub Issue
# Issue #20

Testing Done
------------

# Describe how you have tested this change.
# If this commit is part of a multi-commit PR, you can ignore this, and fill it out in the PR description.
```

Comment: Can you show the hook?

Comment: @dan1st sure, It's done

Comment: This is not a hook... This is a commit message or similar.

Comment: @dan1st ok, you right but why I'm getting this issue with slashes? Do you have any idea? I have that command to installHooks in react project